# On Android what determines the abi that is used for building

Tags: android, xamarin, abi

So I have a .so that is included in some builds but not others.

My prebuild script deletes the .so, the associated .jar removes the library from the build.gradle.

The library is from a 3rd party and I don't have control over asking for x86 or arm-v7. It is only provided to me in arm.

When I build without the library support I am getting errors in Xamarin Test that there is no x86 support for the apk.

What actually controls what abi is supported by the apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my pre build script didn't actually delete the .so file.

It was

rm -rf /core/src/main/jniLibs

Not

rm -rf core/src/main/jniLibs

Answer (score 2):

The `Using Native Libraries` documentation on the Xamarin developer portal explains half of this:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/

The ABIs supported by your Android application are determined by the presence of .so files inside your APK, under the `lib/<ABI>` folders where ABI can be one or more of armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, mips, mips64, x86, x86_64 (the current seven ABIs).

I personally use an application from the Google Play Store that helps assist in what files get deployed:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app

So what happens is that most devices typically support multiple ABIs. Thus you will get a list of supported ABIs that the Android Package Manager uses to install the .so files the device prefers.

Basically the best practice here is to ensure you are putting the optimized libraries in each of the `<ABI>` folders as listed above. Just know that when the application gets installed on the device, only one of the supported architectures will be getting installed.

Many thanks to http://ph0b.com/android-abis-and-so-files/ as a human readable resource.

Otherwise the more technical resource: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html

Comment: I am not using the Xamarin SDK but we are trying to use the Xamarin test tools. I believe I have remove all the elements that should be using ABI but I am still getting an error that the APK only supports arm.

Comment: This applies in Native Android as well. The answer applies what controls what abi is supported by the device. What your error is stating is that the device you are testing on does not find any <ABI> that has x86 support. Thus the APK does not provide any supported <ABI> it is looking for.

Comment: If I am not using an abi and just java then every type should be supported correct?

Comment: The limitation is with regards to CPU instruction sets, endianness of memory stores, etc (Which is what an ABI is)

Comment: My question is guess isn't clear, at what point in the build process does it determine what ABI is need? Since I am deleting the .so, .jar and source files it shouldn't require any ABI.

Comment: See "Android Platform ABI support" - https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#am